# How to pass a constant parameter constraint on scipy.minimize and question on bounds implementation

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, constants

So my problem is that ,I want to run scipy.minimize for a function that takes a list of 3 arguments but keep one of the parameters in the list constant and find the minimization of my function with that constraint.From what I understand,this can be done using the args or constraint option in scipy.minimize but I don't understand how I am supposed to use it if for example I want to keep the first parameter in the list constant.
Here is a bit of the code:

```
def package(self):

    if self.choose<=2:
        boun=[(0.001,4),(0.001,4),(0.001,0.999)]
              self.minimised_f=scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(self.nll,boun,polish=True)
        print(self.minimised_f)
        self.min_param=self.minimised_f.x
        print(self.minimised_f.fun)
        print(self.min_param)



def nll(self,parameters):

        self.mean_life_1=parameters[0]
        self.mean_life_2=parameters[1]
        self.F=parameters[2]

    nll=0.0

    for i in range(0,len(self.values)):

        if self.choose==1 or self.choose==3 and self.fun_t(self.t_values[i])>0:
            l=-math.log(self.fun_t(self.t_values[i]))
        elif self.choose==2 or self.choose==4 and self.fun_t_the(self.t_values[i],self.theta_values[i])>0 :
            l=-math.log(self.fun_t_the(self.t_values[i],self.theta_values[i]))
        else:
            l=0
        nll+=l
    return nll
def fun_t(self,t):

    p1=1.0/self.mean_life_1*math.exp(-t/self.mean_life_1)
    p2=1.0/self.mean_life_2*math.exp(-t/self.mean_life_2)
    f=self.F*p1+(1-self.F)*p2
    return f

def fun_t_the(self,t,theta):

    p1=1.0/(3.0*math.pi*self.mean_life_1)*(1.0+(math.cos(theta))**2)*math.exp(-t/self.mean_life_1)
    p2=1.0/(math.pi*self.mean_life_2)*(math.sin(theta))**2*math.exp(-t/self.mean_life_2)
    f=self.F*p1+(1-self.F)*p2
    return f
```

Also the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution method doesn't seem to obey the bounds conditions I have set for the parameters.If I remove the conditions in the nll function where I require the function to be above zero I get an error when it tries to calculate the log of a negative number.The reason I am thinking it doesn't obey the bounds is because the only way for fun_t to become negative is if F is outside the range (0,1).Does anyone know if there are any actual issues with its implementation under bounds for the parameters?

Comment: Wrap the objective function in a new function that sets one of the elements of the input to a constant. That is, if the original objective function (that takes a vector of length 3) is `func(x)`, and you want to set, say, x[0] = c, use `def wrapper(x): return func([c, x[0], x[1]])`.  Now `wrapper` is a function that takes a sequence of length 2 as its argument.

Comment: It is always easier to help if more details are provided. Could you show your functions and constraints, the value of the fixed parameter etc?! Could you show your implementation using `differential_evolution` and point to the violations of the constraints you observe?